# Isolated Azure Functions project CosmosDbOutput attribute, get id back

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0

Azure Functions .NET 6 - `CosmosDBOutput` binding. Is it possible to retrieve the ID cosmos db made for your document? Or do you have to create the ID yourself then and put it in the `newItem` property? I don't want to do that because then you can get 2 times the same ID in your DB. Suggestions on what I can do?

```
    [Function("CreateItem")]
    [CosmosDBOutput("%DatabaseName%","%CollectionName%", 
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString", CreateIfNotExists = true)]
    public static async Task<object> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route="items")] HttpRequestData requestData
    )
    {
        var newItem = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Item>(requestData.Body);
        return newItem;
    }
```

Comment: What would you like to do with the ID? Because the ID is known after completion of your function? So the only way would be to generate the ID yourself.

Comment: @AntonR to return to the one who called the function so they know what item they have created with what id